# How to find number from text

Tags: pyspark

This is a small example of a pyspark column (String) in my dataframe.

```
 column                                                                                            |   new_column
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
Hoy es día de ABC/KE98789T983456 clase.                                                           |    98789
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
Como ABC/KE 34562Z845673 todas las mañanas                                                        |    34562
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
Hoy tiene ABC/KE 110330/L63868 clase de matemáticas,                                              |    110330
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
Marcos se ABC 898456/L56784 levanta con sueño.                                                    |    898456
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
Marcos se ABC898456 levanta con sueño.                                                            |    898456
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
comienza ABC - KE 60014 -T60058                                                                   |    60014
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
inglés y FOR 102658/L61144 ciencia. Se viste, desayuna                                            |    102658
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
y comienza FOR ABC- 72981 / KE T79581: el camino hacia la                                         |    72981
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
escuela. Se FOR ABC 101665 - 103035 - 101926 - 105484 - 103036 - 103247 - encuentra con su        |    [101665,103035,101926,105484,103036,103247]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
escuela ABCS 206048/206049/206050/206051/205225-FG-matemáticas-                                   |    [206048,206049,206050,206051,205225]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
encuentra ABCS 111553/L00847 & 111558/L00895 - matemáticas                                        |    [111553, 111558]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
ciencia ABC 163278/P20447 AND RETROFIT ABCS 164567/P21000 - 164568/P21001 - desayuna              |    [163278,164567,164568 ]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
ABC/KE 71729/T81672 - 71781/T81674 71782/T81676 71730/T81673 71783/T81677 71784/T                 |    [71729,71781,71782,71730,71783,71784]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |--------------------------------------------------
ciencia ABC/KE2646/L61175:E/F-levanta con sueño L61/62LAV AT Z5CTR/XC D3-1593                     |    [2646]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
escuela ABCS 6048/206049/6050/206051/205225-FG-matemáticas- MSN 2345                              |    [6048,206049,6050,206051,205225]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOR ABC/KE 109038_L35674_DEFINE AND DESIGN IMPROVEMENTS OF 1618 FROM 118(PDS4 BRACKETS)           |   [109038]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
y comienza FOR ABC- 2981 / KE T79581: el camino hacia la 9856                                     |   [2981]
```

I want to extract all numbers that contain: 4, 5 or 6 digits from this text.
Condition and cases to extract them:

```
- Attached to ABC/KE (first line in the example above).
- after ABC/KE + space (second and third line).
- after ABC + space (line 4)
- after ABC without space (line 5)
- after ABC - KE + space
- after for word
- after ABC- + space
- after ABC + space
- after ABCS (line 10 and 11)
```

Example of failed cases:

```
                                    Column                                                    |   new_column
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOR ABC/KE 109038_L35674_DEFINE AND DESIGN IMPROVEMENTS OF 1618 FROM 118(PDS4 BRACKETS)           |   [1618]   ==> should be [109038]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ciencia ABC/KE2646/L61175:E/F-levanta con sueño L61/62LAV AT Z5CTR/XC D3-1593                     |   [1593]  ==> should be [2646]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
escuela ABCS 6048/206049/6050/206051/205225-FG-matemáticas- MSN 2345                              |    [6048,206049,6050,206051,205225, 2345]  ==> should be [6048,206049,6050,206051,205225]
```

I hope that I resumed the cases, you can see my example above and the expect output.
How can I do it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using regexes to clean out the data and set up a lone anchor with value of `ABC` to identify the start of a potential match. after str.split(), iterate through the resulting array to flag and retrieve consecutive matching numbers that follow this anchor.

**Edit:** Added underscore `_` into the data pattern (`\b(\d{4,6})(?=[A-Z/_]|$)`) so that it now allows underscore as an anchor to follow the matched substring of 4-6 digit. this fixed the first line, line 2 and 3 should be working with the existing regex patterns.

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
```

(1) Use regex patterns to clean out the raw data so that we have only one anchor `ABC` to identify the start of a potential match:

- **clean1**: use `[-&\s]+` to convert '&', '-' and whitespaces to a SPACE `' '`, they are used to connect a chain of numbers

  ```
  example: `ABC - KE`  -->  `ABC KE`
           `103035 - 101926 - 105484` -> `103035 101926 105484`
           `111553/L00847 & 111558/L00895` -> `111553/L00847 111558/L00895`
  ```
- **clean2**: convert text matching the following three sub-patterns into `'ABC '`

  ```
  + ABCS?(?:[/\s]+KE|(?=\s*\d))
    + ABC followed by an optional `S`
      + followed by at least one slash or whitespace and then `KE` --> `[/\s]+KE`
        example: `ABC/KE 110330/L63868` to `ABC  110330/L63868`
      + or followed by optional whitespaces and then at least one digit  --> (?=\s*\d)
        example: ABC898456 -> `ABC 898456`
  + \bFOR\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s+)*
    + `FOR` words
        example: `FOR DEF HJK 12345` -> `ABC 12345`
  ```
- **data**: *\b(\d{4,6})(?=[A-Z/_]|$)* is a regex to match actual numbers: 4-6 digits followed by [A-Z/] or end_of_string

(2) Create a dict to save all 3 patterns:

```
ptns = {
    'clean1': re.compile(r'[-&\s]+', re.UNICODE)
  , 'clean2': re.compile(r'\bABCS?(?:[/\s-]+KE|(?=\s*\d))|\bFOR\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s+)*', re.UNICODE)
  , 'data'  : re.compile(r'\b(\d{4,6})(?=[A-Z/_]|$)', re.UNICODE)
}
```

(3) Create a function to find matched numbers and save them into an array

```
def find_number(s_t_r, ptns, is_debug=0):
  try:
    arr = re.sub(ptns['clean2'], 'ABC ', re.sub(ptns['clean1'], ' ', s_t_r.upper())).split()
    if is_debug: return arr
    # f: flag to identify if a chain of matches is started, default is 0(false)
    f = 0
    new_arr = []
    # iterate through the above arr and start checking numbers when anchor is detected and set f=1
    for x in arr:
      if x == 'ABC':
        f = 1
      elif f:
        new = re.findall(ptns['data'], x)
        # if find any matches, else reset the flag
        if new:
          new_arr.extend(new)
        else:
          f = 0
    return new_arr
  except Exception as e:
    # only use print in local debugging
    print('ERROR:{}:\n  [{}]\n'.format(s_t_r, e))
    return []
```

(4) defind the udf function

```
udf_find_number = udf(lambda x: find_number(x, ptns), ArrayType(StringType()))
```

(5) get the new_column

```
df.withColumn('new_column', udf_find_number('column')).show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|column                                                                                    |new_column                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|Hoy es da de ABC/KE98789T983456 clase.                                                    |[98789]                                         |
|Como ABC/KE 34562Z845673 todas las ma?anas                                                |[34562]                                         |
|Hoy tiene ABC/KE 110330/L63868 clase de matem篓垄ticas,                                    |[110330]                                        |
|Marcos se ABC 898456/L56784 levanta con sue?o.                                            |[898456]                                        |
|Marcos se ABC898456 levanta con sue?o.                                                    |[898456]                                        |
|comienza ABC - KE 60014 -T60058                                                           |[60014]                                         |
|ingl篓娄s y FOR 102658/L61144 ciencia. Se viste, desayuna                                  |[102658]                                        |
|y comienza FOR ABC- 72981 / KE T79581: el camino hacia la                                 |[72981]                                         |
|escuela. Se FOR ABC 101665 - 103035 - 101926 - 105484 - 103036 - 103247 - encuentra con su|[101665, 103035, 101926, 105484, 103036, 103247]|
|escuela ABCS 206048/206049/206050/206051/205225-FG-matem篓垄ticas-                         |[206048, 206049, 206050, 206051, 205225]        |
|encuentra ABCS 111553/L00847 & 111558/L00895 - matem篓垄ticas                              |[111553, 111558]                                |
|ciencia ABC 163278/P20447 AND RETROFIT ABCS 164567/P21000 - 164568/P21001 - desayuna      |[163278, 164567, 164568]                        |
|ABC/KE 71729/T81672 - 71781/T81674 71782/T81676 71730/T81673 71783/T81677 71784/T         |[71729, 71781, 71782, 71730, 71783, 71784]      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

(6) code for debugging, use `find_number(row.column, ptns, 1)` to check how/if the first two regex patterns work as expected:

```
for row in df.limit(10).collect():
  print('{}:\n    {}\n'.format(row.column, find_number(row.column, ptns)))
```

**Some Notes:**

- in `clean2` pattern, ABCS and ABS are treated the same way. if they are different, just remove the 'S' and add a new alternative `ABCS\s*(?=\d)` to the end of the pattern

  ```
  re.compile(r'\bABC(?:[/\s-]+KE|(?=\s*\d))|\bFOR\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s+)*|ABCS\s*(?=\d)')
  ```
- current pattern `clean1` only treats '-', '&' and whitespaces as consecutive connector, you might add more characters or words like 'and', 'or', for example:

  ```
  re.compile(r'[-&\s]+|\b(?:AND|OR)\b')
  ```
- `FOR words` is \bFOR\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s+)*, this might be adjusted based on if numbers are allowed in words etc.
- This was tested on Python-3. using Python-2, there might be issue with unicode, you can fix it by using the method in the first answer of [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

Comment: Hi @jxc, 
It's working for 5 and 6 digits thanks, but no for the 4 digits. I got a wrong numbers that contain 4 digits yes, but doesn't respect the pattern conditions like 5 and 6 digits.
I'm sorry fir this delay, some help please ? Thank you

Comment: @verojoucla, can yo add all samples that failed, I will need to check what exactly happened.

Comment: Comment is corrected, sorry :) The idea is always I should respect the existing of the words ABC, ABCS, FOR and KE. I edited the question, I added 3 lines in the end of the example of a dataset. And I added an example of the failed cases . Thank you very much

Comment: @verojoucla, I tested te 3 new samples, 2nd and 3rd ones should be working. and the 1st one, just need a small adjustment change the pattern for data to:  , `'data'  : re.compile(r'\b(\d{4,6})(?=[A-Z/_]|$)', re.UNICODE)`. I just added so that the 4-6 numbers must be followed by a uppercase letter, a slash or underscore (underscore was missing from previous one). that should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's worked well. And I have posted a new question, I want just to add some conditions to this pattern, don't touch to the old cases. So may be you only can help again :) Thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755555/modify-a-pattern-to-extract-number-from-text