# Modify a pattern to find number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have this pattern to extract numbers from Strings.

```
ptns = { 'clean1': re.compile(r'[-&\s]+', re.UNICODE)
        , 'clean2': re.compile(r'\bABCS?(?:[/\s-]+KE|(?=\s*\d))|\bFOR\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s+)*', re.UNICODE) 
        , 'data' : re.compile(r'\b(\d{4,6})(?=[A-Z/_]|$)', re.UNICODE) }
```

I want to add some conditions to the pattern, and don’t touch to the old contitions, always should I have the words : `ABCDEFGS, ABCDEFG,  ABC, JUSTIF` in the begin.
Some times I have an optional `‘S’` in the end of the string like : ABCDEFGS.

I want to extract all numbers that contain: `4, 5 or 6` digits from this text. Condition and cases to add to the pattern to extract the numbers:

```
- Attached to ABC then ‘.’ (sometimes I have only one number sometimes I have a list of a numbers) 
- Attached to ABC space then ‘.’ (sometimes I have only one number sometimes I have a list of a numbers) 
- after ABCDEFGS then space
- after ABCDEFG + space (line 4) 
- after JUSTIF then ‘.’ space 
- After ABC but between ( ) ⇒ See example bellow.
```

Dataset example and expect result is:

```
Column                                                                                                                New_column
————————————————————————————————————————
Hoy es día  ABCDEFGS 05327 - 05771 - 06045 todas las mañanas   | [05327, 05771, 06045]     
———————————————————————————————————————— 
 todas las mañanas ABCDEFG 6661 & ABCDEFG 11440 Se viste    | [6661, 11440 ]
————————————————————————————————————————
escuela ABCDEFG 19652 matemáticas Hoy es día               | [19652]
————————————————————————————————————————
y comienza ABCDEFG 76192/T85921 el camino hacia             | [76192]
————————————————————————————————————————
Marcos se ABCDEFG 13462 S22786 camino                        | [13462]
————————————————————————————————————————
encuentra con su ABC. 19390 / 19351 viste, desayuna           | [19390, 19351]
————————————————————————————————————————
escuela ABC.5498/5499/5470/5471 DEFINE AND DESIGN IMPROVE     | [5498,5499,5470,5471]
————————————————————————————————————————
l camino hacia la ABC.20974 Marcos se                       | [20974]
————————————————————————————————————————
todas las mañanas ABC 160879-P15989/ 160878-P20181/160878-P20182 AND 160879-P20183 [160879, 160878, 160878, 160879]
————————————————————————————————————————
ABC. 5498/5499/5470/5471 l camino hacia la                  | [5498,5499,5470,5471]
————————————————————————————————————————
todas las JUSTIF. 103383/L25469   todas                                                     | [103383]
————————————————————————————————————————
las (ABC 38770) OR CFM56-5B1/3 (ABC 37147)  camino             |      [38770, 37147]
————————————————————————————————————————
hacia la (POST ABC 161104)  hacia la                             | [161104]
————————————————————————————————————————
DEFINE AND DESIG ABC/KE: 73620T80840 DEFINE      | [73620 ]
————————————————————————————————————————
 DEFINE AND DESIGN IMPROVE ABC (39729)  IMPROVE    |  [39729]
————————————————————————————————————————
```

Comment: Which language/regex engine?

Comment: pyspark; Spark < 2.4

Comment: What is the rule behind matching `73620` in `73620T80840`? Same goes for `39729` in last line (it doesn't contain 4, 5, or 6)? Does the optional `S` appear only after `ABCDEFG`, or can it appear after the other options too (`ABCS` and `JUSTIFS`)?

Comment: How does `73620` get matched in `73620T80840`? Is that a typo and there's supposed to be a space?

Comment: The `ABCDEFGS, ABCDEFG,  ABC, JUSTIF`, etc are you simply ensuring they exist in the string, or that they precede the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request, I modified the three patterns which are used to  clean data and match the numbers:

**EDIT:** in the *data* pattern, replaced `\b` with `(?:^|(?<=/))` so that the numbers can either at the beginning of string or preceded by a slash `/`.

```
ptns = { 'clean1': re.compile(r'[/-]\s|\s[/-]|[&\s.():]+|\b(?:AND|OR)\b', re.UNICODE)
       , 'clean2': re.compile(r'\bABCS?[/\s]+KE|\b(?:ABCS?|ABCDEFGS?|JUSTIF|FOR)(?=\s*\d)', re.UNICODE)  
       , 'data'  : re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<=/))(\d{4,6})(?=[A-Z/_-]|$)', re.UNICODE) }
```

**Patterns:**

- **clean1**: convert the following patterns into a SPACE

  - `[/-]\s|\s[/-]`: slash or hyphen preceded by a space or followed by a space

    ```
    example:  'ABC- 72981' --> 'ABC 72981'
              'ABC 160879-P15989/' <-- no change since no SPACE around hyphen
    ```
  - `\b(?:AND|OR)\b`: to allow *AND* or *OR* to link a sequence of numbers

    ```
    example: '160878-P20181/160878-P20182 AND 160879-P20183' --> '160878-P20181/160878-P20182 160879-P20183'
    ```
  - `[&\s.():]+`: remove hyphen which needs to be processed separately, added parenthesis `(`, `)`, dot `.` and colon `:`

    ```
    example:   'ABC. 19390'   --> 'ABC 19390'
               '(ABC 38770)'  --> 'ABC 38770'
               'ABC/KE: 73620T80840' --> 'ABC/KE 73620T80840'
    ```
- **clean2**: convert the following into `ABC`

  - `\bABCS?[/\s]+KE`:  ABC followed by a spaces or slashes then following by `KE`. this part might be moved to the *clean1* pattern if the same rules are applied also to JUSTIF, ABCDEFGS? etc.
  - `\b(?:ABCS?|ABCDEFGS?|JUSTIF|FOR)(?=\s*\d)`:  matches ABC. ABCS, ABCDEFG, ABCDEFGS or JUSTIF followed by an optional space and then number
- **data**: added the hyphen `-` as an anchor to follow the matched substring of 4-6 digit

Other code should be kept, see below:

```
udf_find_number = udf(lambda x: find_number(x, ptns), ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn('new_column', udf_find_number('column')).show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|Column                                                                            |new_column                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|Hoy es d陋a  ABCDEFGS 05327 - 05771 - 06045 todas las ma?anas                     |[05327, 05771, 06045]           |
| todas las ma?anas ABCDEFG 6661 & ABCDEFG 11440 Se viste                          |[6661, 11440]                   |
|escuela ABCDEFG 19652 matem垄ticas Hoy es d陋a                                    |[19652]                         |
|y comienza ABCDEFG 76192/T85921 el camino hacia                                   |[76192]                         |
|Marcos se ABCDEFG 13462 S22786 camino                                             |[13462]                         |
|encuentra con su ABC. 19390 / 19351 viste, desayuna                               |[19390, 19351]                  |
|escuela ABC.5498/5499/5470/5471 DEFINE AND DESIGN IMPROVE                         |[5498, 5499, 5470, 5471]        |
|l camino hacia la ABC.20974 Marcos se                                             |[20974]                         |
|todas las ma?anas ABC 160879-P15989/ 160878-P20181/160878-P20182 AND 160879-P20183|[160879, 160878, 160878, 160879]|
|ABC. 5498/5499/5470/5471 l camino hacia la                                        |[5498, 5499, 5470, 5471]        |
|todas las JUSTIF. 103383/L25469   todas                                           |[103383]                        |
|las (ABC 38770) OR CFM56-5B1/3 (ABC 37147)  camino                                |[38770, 37147]                  |
|hacia la (POST ABC 161104)  hacia la                                              |[161104]                        |
|DEFINE AND DESIG ABC/KE: 73620T80840 DEFINE                                       |[73620]                         |
| DEFINE AND DESIGN IMPROVE ABC (39729)  IMPROVE                                   |[39729]                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Let me know if this fixed the problems.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202294/discussion-on-answer-by-jxc-modify-a-pattern-to-extract-number-from-text).